# accessing property value in ivy which was set from ant script

Tags: ant, ivy

I have a build.xml file with ant script
In build.xml, I am setting a value to property env.REVISION,
The value set to it inside a target is not accessible outside of it.
For example in the following code ${env.REVISION} is set to 1.0.1.0
but echo inside target "Get_Revision" gives correct value but echo inside the target "run" doesn't substitute the version number. The echo statement gives the output as 
${env.REVISION}

```
<project name="module_name" default="run" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">
  ...
  <target name="run" description="Run" depends="Get_Revision">
    <antcall target="Get_Revision" />
    <echo>${env.REVISION}</echo>
    <ivy:retrieve/>
  </target>
  <target name="Get_Revision" description ="Gets the revision number">
    ...
    <property name="env.REVISION" value="1.0.1.0" />
    <echo>${env.REVISION}</echo>
    ...
  </target>
  ...
</project>
```

Also, I would like to use this property ${env.REVISION} to be used in the ivy.xml file as well.

Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

When you use the [antcall](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/antcall.html) task, you create a new context:

> The called target(s) are run in a new project; be aware that this
>   means properties, references, etc. set by called targets will not
>   persist back to the calling project.

In your example as shown, you are using a `depends` declaration on your `run` target, as well as an `antcall`, to the `Get_Revision` target.

The `antcall` will not give the result you want, for the reason given above.

However, the `depends` does give the result you want. Are you sure that your test scenario (second echo) fails when the `depends` is included?

BTW, the `env.` prefix is conventionally used for properties loaded from environment variables using like this:

```
<property environment="env"/>
<echo>${env.SOME_VAR_NAME}</echo>
```

Comment: Sorry, I was not using the depends="Get_REvision" in my actual script. But I don't want to use depends in that case..only antcall

Comment: antcallback task works fine when the property set inside the target has to be returned back to the caller